# Is there a simple way of calculating determinant of "reverse arrowhead" matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant, laplace-expansion

I have some problems with finding the determinant of the following matrix.

I have tried a simple Laplace expansion on the first row, but I have a feeling I am missing some simple trick here.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    y_{n} & 0 & 0 & \dots &0  & y_{1} \\
    0& y_{n} & 0 & \dots &0  & y_{2} \\
0&0& y_{n}  & \dots &0  & y_{3} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\vdots \\
    0  & 0 & 0&\dots  & y_{n}  & y_{n-1} \\
    -y_{n} & -y_{n} & -y_{n} & \dots &-y_{n} & 1- \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}y_i
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Besides that, while I was doing this I got interested in computing the determinant of [arrowhead matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowhead_matrix) and I can not find something that helps.

Comment: Try expanding on the last row or column instead

Comment: Just use the fact that the determinant is unchanged under addition of one row to another. Successively add rows $1,\ldots,n-1$ to row $n$. The resulting matrix is upper triangular so the determinant is just the product of the diagonal entries, namely $y_n^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with dim. 2 and 3, it is not difficult
to deduce, and then demonstrate that it holds for all 2 <= dim., 
that the LU decomposition of your matrix is

$$
\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & 0 &  \cdots  & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & 1 &  \cdots  & 0 & 0  \\
    \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots   \\
   0 & 0 &  \cdots  & 1 & 0  \\
   { - 1} & { - 1} &  \cdots  & { - 1} & 1  \\
 \end{array} } \right]\;\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {y_n } & 0 &  \cdots  & 0 & {y_1 }  \\
   0 & {y_n } &  \cdots  & 0 & {y_2 }  \\
    \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots   \\
   0 & 0 &  \cdots  & {y_n } & {y_{n - 1} }  \\
   0 & 0 &  \cdots  & 0 & 1  \\
 \end{array} } \right]
$$
By the way, many times "arrow-head" m. decompose LU in "half-arrow-head".